# Disable the selected option while clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

[enter link description here][2]

how to disable the previously selected field while selecting add button and remove the disable while pressing the remove button. This flow should be continued until the end.
here is the link
**Note:
disable functionality is only for the selected options not for select. In the next row that option should be disabled and while removing that option should be enabled**

its like loop while clicking on the add button(disable the selected field option ) and remove button (enable the selected option button)

Please see below code you can able to track it.

```js
  
      var staticPrefills = [{
          "questionId": "5e578b7d30bb2fd60c1f9855",
          "note": "Mobile Number",
          "prefillValue": null
        },
        {
          "questionId": "5e578b8930bb2fd60c1f985c",
          "note": "Email",
          "prefillValue": null
        },
        {
          "questionId": "5e578b9330bb2fd60c1f985f",
          "note": "Name",
          "prefillValue": null
        },
        {
          "questionId": "5e578ba930bb2fd60c1f9862",
          "note": "Agent ID",
          "prefillValue": null
        },
      ]
      var staffPrefillArray = []
   function generateJson(){
  var divchildlength =  $("#buildyourform").children().length;
  staffPrefillArray = [];
        for(var i = 0;  i < divchildlength; i++ ){
         var selectValue=   $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) select`).val();
         var textValue=   $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) input`).val();
         var selectAttrValue = $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) select option:selected`).attr('questionId');
        //  console.log(selectValue);
        //  console.log(textValue);
        //  console.log(selectAttrValue);
         var generateJsonvalue = {
          "questionId": selectAttrValue,
        "note": selectValue,
        "prefillValue": textValue
         }
         staffPrefillArray.push(generateJsonvalue);

        }
        console.log(staffPrefillArray);
      }
  
      for(var i=0; i<staticPrefills.length; i++){
              $('#static-select-prefills').append(`<option questionId="${staticPrefills[i].questionId}" value="${staticPrefills[i].note}"> 
              ${staticPrefills[i].note} 
             
         </option>`);
             }
          
      var clicks = 1;
      var s = 1;
      $("#btn-addfield").click(function () {
        if (staticPrefills.length > clicks) {
          var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
          var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
          var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
          fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
          var sName = `<select class="fieldtype select-text"  name="notes" value="">
  ${staticPrefills.map(txtvalue => `<option questionId="${txtvalue.questionId}" value="${txtvalue.note}">${txtvalue.note}</option>`)}
  </select>`;
          var fName = $(`<input type="text" class="fieldname form__field" name="value" value="" required />`);
          var removeButton = $(`<button class='remove-field'>-</button>.`);
          removeButton.click(function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            clicks -= 1;
            s -= 1;
          });
  
          fieldWrapper.append(sName);
          fieldWrapper.append(fName);
          fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
  
          $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
          clicks += 1;
          s += 1;
  
        } else {
          alert(
            `You have only configured ${staticPrefills.length} prefill in the WXM product, More than that not allowed`
          );
        }
  
      });
```

```css
    legend {
      padding: 0px 10px;
      background: black;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    .fieldwrapper {
      display: flex;
    }

    input.add {
      float: right;
    }

    input.fieldname {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    select.fieldtype {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    input.remove {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    #yourform label {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    #yourform input,
    #yourform textarea {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    input.fieldname.form__field {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
select.fieldtype.select-text {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
#btn-addfield
{
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}
.remove-field {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #EF5451;
    height:20px;
    width:20px
}
#btn-addfield{
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #EF5451; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-hor">
    <div class="form__group">
      <div id="buildyourform">
        <div class="fieldwrapper" data-questionid="5e578b7d30bb2fd60c1f9855" id="field1">
          <select name="notes" value="" id="static-select-prefills" class="fieldtype select-text">

          </select>
          <input type="text" name="value" value="" class="fieldname form__field" required="">
          <button id="btn-addfield">add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="generateJson()">submit</button>
```

Comment: Did you click POST too early?

Comment: you can see the link to understand the problem [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8ncuje10/)

Comment: There's too much code to look through. Why don't you create a reduced version and post that instead.

Comment: Sorry, I am now only stared to study javascript. Please help me to do it.
just you can focus on disable the selected option while click add and  remove the disable while clicking on the remove

Comment: It's too much effort to help. If you reduce your code two things will happen, you'll more likely find the answer yourself and you'll help us to help you.

People will ignore this question because it's too hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `button` click method you should use the below code

```
$(this).parents().find("select").prop("disabled", true);
```

Traverse to parent element and then find select and add disable property to the element.

```js
var staticPrefills = [{
    "questionId": "5e578b7d30bb2fd60c1f9855",
    "note": "Mobile Number",
    "prefillValue": null
  },
  {
    "questionId": "5e578b8930bb2fd60c1f985c",
    "note": "Email",
    "prefillValue": null
  },
  {
    "questionId": "5e578b9330bb2fd60c1f985f",
    "note": "Name",
    "prefillValue": null
  },
  {
    "questionId": "5e578ba930bb2fd60c1f9862",
    "note": "Agent ID",
    "prefillValue": null
  }
]

var staffPrefillArray = [];

function generateJson(){
  var divchildlength =  $("#buildyourform").children().length;
  staffPrefillArray = [];
  for(var i = 0;  i < divchildlength; i++ ) {
    var selectValue=   $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) select`).val();
    var textValue=   $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) input`).val();
    var selectAttrValue = $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) select option:selected`).attr('questionId');
  
    var generateJsonvalue = {
      "questionId": selectAttrValue,
      "note": selectValue,
      "prefillValue": textValue
    };
    
    staffPrefillArray.push(generateJsonvalue);
  }
  console.log(staffPrefillArray);
}
  
for(var i=0; i<staticPrefills.length; i++){
  $('#static-select-prefills').append(`<option questionId="${staticPrefills[i].questionId}" value="${staticPrefills[i].note}"> 
      ${staticPrefills[i].note} 
 </option>`);
}

var clicks = 1;
var s = 1;

$(".btn-addfield").click(function () {
    if (staticPrefills.length > clicks) {
      $(this).parents().find("select").prop("disabled", true);
      var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
      var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
      var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
      fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
      var sName = `<select class="fieldtype select-text"  name="notes" value="">
${staticPrefills.map(txtvalue => `<option questionId="${txtvalue.questionId}" value="${txtvalue.note}">${txtvalue.note}</option>`)}
</select>`;
      var fName = $(`<input type="text" class="fieldname form__field" name="value" value="" required />`);
      var removeButton = $(`<button class='remove-field'>-</button>.`);
      removeButton.click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        clicks -= 1;
        s -= 1;
      });

    fieldWrapper.append(sName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);

    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    clicks += 1;
    s += 1;

  } else {
    alert(
      `You have only configured ${staticPrefills.length} prefill in the WXM product, More than that not allowed`
    );
  }
});
```

```css
legend {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: #FFF;
}

.fieldwrapper {
  display: flex;
}

input.add {
  float: right;
}

input.fieldname {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

select.fieldtype {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

input.remove {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#yourform label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#yourform input,
#yourform textarea {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
  input.fieldname.form__field {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
select.fieldtype.select-text {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
.btn-addfield
{
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}
.remove-field {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #EF5451;
  height:20px;
  width:20px
}
.btn-addfield{
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #EF5451; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-hor">
  <div class="form__group">
    <div id="buildyourform">
      <div class="fieldwrapper" data-questionid="5e578b7d30bb2fd60c1f9855" id="field1">
        <select name="notes" value="" id="static-select-prefills" class="fieldtype select-text">

        </select>
        <input type="text" name="value" value="" class="fieldname form__field" required="">
        <button class="btn-addfield">add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="generateJson()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the following statement to disable the previously selected field while selecting the add button.

```
$(this).prevAll('select')[0].disabled=true;
```

You may refer to the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/41ngzybs/).

For the second issue, do you want to delete the whole row when the "-" button is clicked?

Comment: disable functionality is only for the selected options not for select. In the next row that option should be disabled and while removing that option should be enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my solution.

You have to create a function to disable, if elems are more than one. and call it on add and remove.

```
    function desableOthers() {
  let elms = $(".fieldwrapper");
  if (elms.length > 1) {
    elms = elms.slice(0, -1);
    elms.each(function() {
      $(this)
        .find(".fieldname.form__field")
        .attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this)
        .find(".fieldtype.select-text")
        .attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    return;
  }
  if (elms.length === 1) {
    $(".fieldwrapper .fieldname.form__field").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".fieldwrapper .fieldtype.select-text").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

**Solution:**

```js
var staticPrefills = [
  {
    questionId: "5e578b7d30bb2fd60c1f9855",
    note: "Mobile Number",
    prefillValue: null
  },
  {
    questionId: "5e578b8930bb2fd60c1f985c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: null
  },
  {
    questionId: "5e578b9330bb2fd60c1f985f",
    note: "Name",
    prefillValue: null
  },
  {
    questionId: "5e578ba930bb2fd60c1f9862",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: null
  }
];
var staffPrefillArray = [];
function generateJson() {
  var divchildlength = $("#buildyourform").children().length;
  staffPrefillArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < divchildlength; i++) {
    var selectValue = $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) select`).val();
    var textValue = $(`#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) input`).val();
    var selectAttrValue = $(
      `#buildyourform div:nth-child(${i + 1}) select option:selected`
    ).attr("questionId");
    //  console.log(selectValue);
    //  console.log(textValue);
    //  console.log(selectAttrValue);
    var generateJsonvalue = {
      questionId: selectAttrValue,
      note: selectValue,
      prefillValue: textValue
    };
    staffPrefillArray.push(generateJsonvalue);
  }
  console.log(staffPrefillArray);
}

for (var i = 0; i < staticPrefills.length; i++) {
  $("#static-select-prefills").append(`<option questionId="${
    staticPrefills[i].questionId
  }" value="${staticPrefills[i].note}"> 
      ${staticPrefills[i].note} 
     
 </option>`);
}
function desableOthers() {
  let elms = $(".fieldwrapper");
  if (elms.length > 1) {
elms = elms.slice(0, -1);
elms.each(function() {
  $(this)
    .find(".fieldname.form__field")
    .attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(this)
    .find(".fieldtype.select-text")
    .attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
return;
  }
  if (elms.length === 1) {
$(".fieldwrapper .fieldname.form__field").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".fieldwrapper .fieldtype.select-text").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
var clicks = 1;
var s = 1;
$("#btn-addfield").click(function() {
  if (staticPrefills.length > clicks) {
    var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
    var intId =
      (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $('<div class="fieldwrapper" id="field' + intId + '"/>');
    fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
    var sName = `<select class="fieldtype select-text"  name="notes" value="">
${staticPrefills.map(
  txtvalue =>
    `<option questionId="${txtvalue.questionId}" value="${txtvalue.note}">${
      txtvalue.note
    }</option>`
)}
</select>`;
    var fName = $(
      `<input type="text" class="fieldname form__field" name="value" value="" required />`
    );
    var removeButton = $(`<button class='remove-field'>-</button>.`);
    removeButton.click(function() {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .remove();
      clicks -= 1;
      s -= 1;
      desableOthers();
    });

    fieldWrapper.append(sName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);

    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    clicks += 1;
    s += 1;
    desableOthers();
  } else {
    alert(
      `You have only configured ${
        staticPrefills.length
      } prefill in the WXM product, More than that not allowed`
    );
  }
});
```

```css
legend {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.fieldwrapper {
  display: flex;
}

input.add {
  float: right;
}

input.fieldname {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

select.fieldtype {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

input.remove {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#yourform label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#yourform input,
#yourform textarea {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
input.fieldname.form__field {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
select.fieldtype.select-text {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
#btn-addfield {
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}
.remove-field {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ef5451;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
#btn-addfield {
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ef5451;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div class="display-hor">
      <div class="form__group">
        <div id="buildyourform">
          <div
            class="fieldwrapper"
            data-questionid="5e578b7d30bb2fd60c1f9855"
            id="field1"
          >
            <select
              name="notes"
              value=""
              id="static-select-prefills"
              class="fieldtype select-text"
            >
            </select>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="value"
              value=""
              class="fieldname form__field"
              required=""
            />
            <button id="btn-addfield">add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="generateJson()">submit</button>
    
  </body>
```

Comment: @The KNVB disable functionality is only for the selected options  not for select. In the next row that option should be disabled and while removing that option should be enabled